# WebStorm can't resolve lodash template delimiter

Tags: lodash, webstorm, template-engine, code-inspection

WebStorm shows inspection errors on lodash template delimiter in js files.
I tried adding the EJS plugin as described in [this issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-679), but it still can't resolve the interpolate tag `<%= ... %>`.

[image]

How to configure WebStorm to resolve lodash templates ?

NB: I'm using WS 2020.2.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Enabling **EJS** plugin is not enough, as it's not about template syntax support (that is provided for `.ejs` files), it's about supporting EJS templates embedded in javascript. You can see parser errors because this is not a valid JavaScript.
Unfortunately there is no way to tell the parser to skip arbitrary parts of code  to avoid errors when building a syntax tree.

I can suggest the following:

- associate the `.js` files with embedded "tags" syntax with **EJS** file type (in **Settings | Editor | File Types**) by adding `<file_name>.js` as a pattern there
- when associating, choose *JavaScript* as template data language for these files

If it doesn't make things any better, the only solution is turning syntax highlighting off for such files... Highlighting level can be configured by clicking the icon in the editor upper right corner. Please see https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2020/05/intellij-idea-2020-2-early-access-program-is-starting/#inspections_widget for details